# How to refresh HTML after AJAX post

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I have a site where guests can sign in via a modal form.
The solution I came up with is working but I feel like it's a dirty/insecure way to do it.
In the master layout, I load the partial view which contains the modal form.

when the user is authenticated I refresh the navbar to show the logged in username. That's the part where I'm kind of confused. Wouldn't it be possible to 'refresh' the navbar which is also a partial view.

**login-modal.blade.php**:

```
<div class="ui small modal" id="loginModal">
<div class="header">
    Login
</div>

<div class="ui active dimmer" id="loader" style="display: none">
    <div class="ui text loader">Loading</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="ui grid">
        <div class="nine wide column centered">
            {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'auth.login', 'method' => 'post','id'=>'formLogin','class' => 'ui large form')) !!}
            <meta name="csrf_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

            <div class="field {!! $errors->has('password') ? 'error' : '' !!}">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                    <i class="user icon"></i>
                    {!! Form::text('username','',['name'=>'username','id'=>'username','class' => 'pd','placeholder'=>'Username']) !!}
                </div>
                {!! $errors->first('username', '<span class="ui text" id="" style="color: #bf4d4b">:message</span>') !!}
            </div>
            <div class="field {!! $errors->has('password') ? 'error' : '' !!}">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                    <i class="lock icon"></i>
                    {!! Form::password('password',['name'=>'password','id'=>'password','class' => '','placeholder'=>'Password']) !!}
                </div>
                {!! $errors->first('password', '<span class="ui text" id="" style="color: #bf4d4b">:message</span>') !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::submit('Login',['id'=>'loginButton','class'=>'ui fluid large teal submit button']) !!}

            <div class="ui error message"></div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}
            <div class="ui message">
                No account? <a href="#"> Sign Up</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
</div>
</div>
```

now the javascript in the same file:

```
<script>
    $('#loginButton').click(function () {
        $('#loginModal').modal(
                {
                    blurring: true,
                    closable: true,
                })
                .modal('show');
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form#formLogin').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                timeout: 10000,
                url: $('form#formLogin').attr('action'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('form#formLogin').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    $('div#loader').show();
                    var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');

                    if (token) {
                        return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                    }
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('div#loader').hide();
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success == false) {
                       var errors = data.errors;                                            $('#loginModal').find('div.field.error').removeClass("field error").addClass("field");
                        $('#loginModal').find('span').remove();
                        $.each(errors, function (field, errormsg) {

                            if (errormsg.length != 0) {

                                var currentField = $('#loginModal').find('#' + field);
                                var currentFieldSpan = $('#loginModal').find('#span' + field);

                                if (currentFieldSpan.length > 0) {
                                    $('#loginModal').find('div.field.error').removeClass("field error").addClass("field");
                                    $('#loginModal').find('span').remove();

                                }
                                currentField.closest("div.field").removeClass("field").addClass("field error");
                                $("<span class='ui text' id='span" + field + "' style='color: #bf4d4b'>" + errormsg + "</span>").insertAfter(currentField.closest("div.ui.left.icon.input"));
                            }
                        });
                        if ((typeof data.locked != 'undefined') && data.locked.status == true) {
                            //BIDOUILLE pour disable le button login//

                            function enableLoginButton() {
                                $('#loginModal').find('#loginButton').removeClass('disabled');
                            }

                            //disable login button
                            $('#loginModal').find('#loginButton').addClass('disabled');
                            //after lockout time enable the login button again
                            setTimeout(enableLoginButton, (data.locked.remainingtime * 1000));

                        }
                    }
                    else if (data.success == true) {//authentication was successful

                        var cnt = '<div class="ui simple dropdown item">' +
                                '<img class="logo" src="{{ asset('images/food.png') }}" style="margin-right: 1em">' +
                                data.user['username'] +
                                ' <i class="dropdown icon"></i>' +
                                '<div class="menu">' +
                                '<a class="item" href="#">Link Item</a>' +
                                '<a class="item" href="#">Link Item</a>' +
                                '<div class="divider"></div>' +
                                '<div class="header">Header Item</div>' +
                                '<div class="item">' +
                                '<i class="dropdown icon"></i>' +
                                'Sub Menu' +
                                '<div class="menu">' +
                                '<a class="item" href="#">Link Item</a>' +
                                '<a class="item" href="#">Link Item</a>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<a class="item" href="#">Link Item</a>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>'

                        //remove the signin button
                        $('#navbartop .right .item').remove();
                        //add the dropdown with username
                        $('#navbartop .right').append(cnt);
                        //dissmis modal
                        $('#loginModal').modal().modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr) {

                    var validationerrors = xhr.responseJSON;
                    $('#loginModal').find('div.field.error').removeClass("field error").addClass("field");
                    $('#loginModal').find('span').remove();
                    $.each(validationerrors, function (field, errormsg) {

                        if (errormsg.length != 0) {

                            //select the field
                            var currentField = $('#loginModal').find('#' + field);
                            var currentFieldSpan = $('#loginModal').find('#span' + field);

                            if (currentFieldSpan.length > 0) {
                                $('#loginModal').find('div.field.error').removeClass("field error").addClass("field");
                                $('#loginModal').find('span').remove();

                            }
                            //apply 'field error' class to the closest div with 'field' class
                            currentField.closest("div.field").removeClass("field").addClass("field error");

                            //appends a span with red text and the validation error message
                            $("<span class='ui text' id='span" + field + "' style='color: #bf4d4b'>" + errormsg + "</span>").insertAfter(currentField.closest("div.ui.left.icon.input"));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

AuthController.php:

```
protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
    {

        if ($throttles) {
            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
            return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
        }

        //if user intended to access Logout() while not logged in, avoid instant redirect and logout
        if (str_contains(redirect()->intended()->getTargetUrl(),'auth/logout')) {
            return redirect()->route('home.index')->with('success', Auth::user()->username.' logged in successfully. ');
        }
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            return Response::json(['success' => true, 'errors' => '','user'=> Auth::user()]);
        }
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())->with('success', Auth::user()->username.' logged in successfully. ');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {


        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

        if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

        if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            return Response::json(['success' => false, 'errors' =>
                [$this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage()]
            ]);
        }
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);


    }
    protected function sendLockoutResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $seconds = app(RateLimiter::class)->availableIn(
            $this->getThrottleKey($request)
        );

        if($request->ajax()) {

                return Response::json(['success' => false,
                    'errors' =>
                        [$this->loginUsername() => $this->getLockoutErrorMessage($seconds)],
                    'locked' =>
                        ['status'=>true, 'remainingtime'=>$seconds]]);

        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->loginUsername() => $this->getLockoutErrorMessage($seconds),
            ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap the navbar into a div like this:

```
<div id="ajax-nav">
<!-- Nav here -->
</div>
```

Then you can reload the navbar when your login response was successful:

```
$('#ajax-nav').load("some url that returns the html of the navbar");
```

Then you just need a route that leads to a Controller that can generate the navbar based on the user login state (logged in or guest).

With this procedure, you can completely replace the content of the navbar with a newly generated one after a specific event like your successful login or you could even set an interval to refresh the navbar - but that should not be needed in your case.

Comment: I did just that, it replaces the navbar fine but i can't interact with it (the links in the navbar don't work) for some reason

Comment: Would you mind showing your html code after the nav has been replaced? And maybe, there are errors in the JavaScript console. Check that too.

Comment: I found why, for some reason a class is added to the body tag `class="dimmable blurring` (i'm using semantic-ui css library). thats why it disables the links of the navbar wierd because i only load the navbar.. whatever

Comment: Okay, so your question is solved? If so, please mark my answer as accepted to make it easier for other users to find a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change this line:

```
'<img class="logo" src="{{ asset('images/food.png') }}" style="margin-right: 1em">'
```

For

```
'<img class="logo" src="{{ asset(\'images/food.png\') }}" style="margin-right: 1em">'
```

I hope it works ;)